# Building an execution string from a text file

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

I am creating a shell script that retrieves values from the database and spools into a text file.  Those values will have variables ($CURR_DATE $SITE etc...) in the database.  So when I want to execute the program with those variables I run into an issue where it is using the literal string and not the value from the variable.

for example.

```
while read line;
      do
         Unix_Array[$counter]=$line;
         let counter=counter+1;
      done < parameterfile.txt
      echo "Finished putting into array"
      while [[ $c -lt ${#Unix_Array[@]} ]]
         do
            PARAMS="${PARAMS:-}${PARAMS:+ }${Unix_Array[$c]}"
            ((c=$c+1))
         done
echo "Finished creating parameter string"


EXECUTE="$PROGRAM $USERID $PARAMS"
echo $PARAMS
$EXECUTE
```

I think it is executing like

```
Program user/id@DB $CURR_DATE $SITE
```

instead of the actual variables that were declared and already set.

How can i build the execution statement so that it will use the variables declared and not the literal variable.

Answer (score 2):

Once you've collected the array, use it directly:

```
typeset -a params
while IFS= read -r line; do
    params[n++]=$line; 
done < parameterfile.txt

"$program" "$userid" "${params[@]}"
```

As to the lines containing variables, I'd hesitantly recommend using `eval`. What does the parameter file look like? Who has permission to write to it?

Get out of the habit of using ALL_CAPS_VARS: one day you'll use PATH or LANG and wonder why things "don't work".

Comment: the parameter file is like param1 $param2 param3 $param4 1 US so its 1 column from the database each parameter is separated by new line so it looks like just 1 column of parameters.

Comment: I added eval before the $EXECUTE and it executed correctly.  What is the issue using eval?

Comment: @Alkey29 `eval` is unsafe if you feed it input that you have no control over (e.g. """data""" from a file that users have write access to or parameters from the command line), you don't want to execute arbitrary code and in *most* cases it can be avoided.